# Behavior of self convolution of 1/n

Tags: summation, closed-form, convolution, upper-lower-bounds

I wish to find a closed form, or a good upper bound for $\sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1} \frac{1}{i \times (n-i)}$.

I can specify a lower bound of $(n-1)/n^2$, which looks like $1/n$ because we have $n-1$ terms are greater than $1/n^2$, and an upper bound in the neighborhood $log(n)$ due to individual terms being less than $1/i$, and our knowledge that sums of $1/i$ approximate the log function but that's about it.

Note that this is also the convolution of $1/n$ with itself, if this helps.

Comment: @Ramanujan: I would have thought $\frac{1}{k (n - k)} = \frac{1}{n} \left( \frac{1}{n - k} + \frac{1}{k}\right)$ might be more useful

Comment: I put in $1/(n-i)*i$  which gave me $$\frac{1}{ni} - \frac{1}{n\times (i-n)}$$ Factoring out the $n$ gives me the sum of two harmonics which is sufficient for me to approximate my function to $2*log(n)/n$, If my calculations are precise.

Comment: @ConfusedSoul  Yes: that is not far away for large $n$.  Or you could say it is between $\frac{2}n(\log (n-1)+\gamma)+\frac1{n(n-1)}-\frac1{4n(n-1)^2}$ and $\frac{2}n(\log (n-1)+\gamma)+\frac1{n(n-1)}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Requested in comments:*

User:Ramanujan suggested dividing up the summand into partial fractions.

You found  $\frac{1}{i (n-i)} = \frac{1}{ni} + \frac{1}{n (n-i)}$ (reversing two signs since $n>i$) and so related to the sum of two [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)), and suggested the reasonable approximation $2\log(n)/n.$

Since the sum is exactly $\frac2nH_{n-1}$, you could find tighter bounds and say it is between $\dfrac{2}n(\log (n-1)+\gamma)+\dfrac1{n(n-1)}-\dfrac1{4n(n-1)^2}$ and $\dfrac{2}n(\log (n-1)+\gamma)+\dfrac1{n(n-1)},$ where $\gamma\approx 0.5772156649$ is the  Euler–Mascheroni constant.

Comment: The constant $4$ in the lower bound can actually be replaced by $6$, which is the best possible.